# How to use cookies to remember a webpage's text size?

Tags: javascript, html

firstly I know that most browsers now have font resizing and zoom etc, but this was specific to my task. Basically I have added the script below which is run each time one of the submit buttons is pressed, making the webpage text size bigger and smaller..

```
 <script>
function resizeText(multiplier) {
  if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
    document.body.style.fontSize = "0.75em";
  }
  document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.1) + "em";
}
</script>


<form>
<input type="submit" class="button"
  onclick="resizeText(-1);return false;"
  name="theme" value="Small" id="normal2">
<input type="submit" class="button"
  onclick="resizeText(1);return false;"
  name="theme" value="Large" id="contrast2">
</form>
```

My question is however, how using cookies do I save this preference so that when the page is reloaded it remembers the selected text size? I've been trying for hours now with no luck. Any guidance is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Dou you really, really want to use cookies? They are going to be sent to the server with each and every request! Usually this is saved in a database on the server side for the currently logged in user, which has the additional advantage of making this "per-user" and not "per-browser".

Answer (score 0):

Read through this: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

`You can use the createcookie function to save the settings, when the settings are changed, or when the page is exited (using onunload/onbeforeunload).`